# LYX- Adding Headers

Tags: header-footer, lyx

Why can't I find **Header & Footer** when I open an new file in LyX?

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Add the Document > Settings... > Modules > **Custom Header/Footerlines** module:

[image]

This will give you access to provide header/footer specifications:

[image]

Also, you can add the headers/footer manually using Document > Settings... > LaTeX Preamble and adding the [`fancyhdr` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr):

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}% Clear header footer
% Other fancyhdr settings...
% ...
```